# libvlc - Control Panel / Элементы управления

Tags: java, android, kotlin, vlc, rtsp

Как включить элементы управления в плеере из библиотеки libvlc?

Вот часть кода, в которой происходит инициализация просмотра rtsp потока:

```
var url = "rtsp://..."

lateinit var mediaLayout: VLCVideoLayout
lateinit var libVLC: LibVLC
lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    libVLC = LibVLC(this, ArrayList<String>().apply {
        add("--no-drop-late-frames")
        add("--no-skip-frames")
        add("--rtsp-tcp")
        add("-vvv")
    })
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer(libVLC)
    mediaLayout = findViewById(R.id.video_layout)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    mediaPlayer.attachViews(mediaLayout, null, false, true)
    val media = Media(libVLC, Uri.parse(url)).apply {
        setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false);
        addOption(":network-caching=150");
        addOption(":clock-jitter=0");
        addOption(":clock-synchro=0");
        mediaPlayer.media = this
    }
    mediaPlayer.media = media
    media.release()
    mediaPlayer.play()
}
```

Собственно, при тапе по плееру не появляется элементов управления. Есть ли они вообще в данной библиотеке, и, если да, то как их включить?